# How to make arrow headlength longer in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

As shown in the plot below, the arrow headlength is too short, it does not look nice, so I would like to make the headlength longer as indicated in the plot by hand drafting.

[image]

Of course, you can make the arrow longer to realize this as in this link:
[Python annotation arrows with same headlength](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27321404/python-annotation-arrows-with-same-headlength)

However, I do not want to change the length of this arrow due to limited space in the plot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to do this through the `frac` [arrowprops key](http://matplotlib.org/users/annotations_intro.html), which corresponds to the fraction of the arrow length occupied by the head. A MWE is given below.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np   

frac_val = 0.1
for x in np.arange(0.1, 1, 0.2):

    arrow_props = dict(fc='k', ec='k', frac=frac_val, headwidth=10, width=2,
                       shrink=0.1)

    text = '%d%%' % (frac_val * 100)

    plt.annotate(text, xy=(x, 0.9), xytext=(x, 0.2), ha='center',
                 arrowprops=arrow_props)

    frac_val += 0.1

plt.show()
```

which results in:

[image]

Comment: plt.annotate('hi','%d%%' % (frac_val * 100), xy=(x, 0.9), xytext=(x, 0.2),
                 ha='center', arrowprops=arrow_props), but when I add text, it does not work...

Comment: @user3737702 Try this instead : `plt.annotate('hi', xy=(x, 0.9), xytext=(x, 0.2), ha='center', arrowprops=arrow_props)`, because `'%d%%' % (frac_val * 100)` is the text argument in my example.

Comment: @user3737702 I've updated my example, so that the text argument is now defined outside of the `plt.annotate`. Should be less misleading.

Comment: That helps in any way, sorry for my carelessness~